# Как организовать роутинг из базы данных в Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony

К сожалению не могу не могу найти нормального примера в документации есть похожее на http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html
но чувствую, это вариант мне от части подходит.

Ситуация допустим есть сайт каталог:

site.ru/{+d}/ - выводит все товары в зависимости от паджинации

site.ru/{slug}/ - а так может выводится страница категории, либо продукта в зависимости от slug (проблема заключается что в каждой таблице категории или продукта есть соответствующее поле slug - можно конечно сделать одну таблицу (или сделать представление) и по связи один к одному получать нужный слаг и тогда все будет намного проще, используя forwarding)

т. е. обычная логика перенаправлять в нужный контроллер-экшен в зависимости от того, что пришло в параметре
можно конечно нахалтурить, и в Index контроллере сделать все эти проверки и через сервис вытащить нужную логику, либо пойти по легкому пути (site.ru/category/{slug}/  и site.ru/product/{slug}/),
но хочется где-то поглядеть как это сделать текущую ситуацию максимально "правильным" подходом?

Comment: а `site.ru/catalog/{category_slug}/{product_slug}/` чем не подходит?

Comment: Задача ТЗ такое все чпу от корня,  может потому чтоб урл не был слишком длинным, ну и в варианте когда указано в одном урле категория и продукт начнутся проблемы когда товар в нескольких категорий и допустип в хлебных крошках надо указать ту категорию с какой зашел пользователь а не главную хотя это с точки программирования бред но видел подобные костыли....

Comment: бредовая идея.. но уж раз стоит такая задача, я бы все равно как то разграничивал все на уровне маршрутов...и делал бы просто более тонкие различия...к примеру категории бы шли просто от корня `site.ru/{slug}`, а продукты бы имели расширение `site.ru/{slug}.xhtml` ... или же перед продуктом бы стоял идентификатор, а потом код `site.ru/{id}_{slug}`

Comment: но в первую очередь я бы отговаривал заказчика(или кто там у Вас) от такой идеи...ибо она ведет в тупик

Comment: Да я согласен что это гемморой на ровном месте, просто в симфони у меня малый допустим на юии2 я бы относительно просто выкрутился, а тут у заказчика может сложится мнения что у меня низкая квалификация и что доказать свое нужно предоставить два полноценно реализованных варианта и предоставить уже на примере минусы и плюсы подходов

Comment: не вижу каких то принципиальных различий между симфони и вторым юии в маршрутизации...

Comment: тут то как раз таки и смысл в том чтобы лишнюю работу не делать... контроллеров может быть огромное множество...еще больше может быть экшенов...использовать для всего этого один плейсхолдер - самоубийство...да и поисковые системы не смогут построить нормальную  структуру сайта без явной вложенности...

Comment: В юии просто можно написать сервис для urlmanager где можно распарсить входящие данные

Comment: Кстати это может и не закончится просто так есть еще инфостраницы типа о нас, контакты и тд которые скорее всего будут тоже иметь чпу от корня

Comment: о чем я и говорил

Comment: а что мешает Вам тоже самое в симфони делать?

Comment: Свой лоадер маршрутов: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html а как сам маршрут создать можно посмотреть в описании компонента http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html ...

Comment: Спасибо гляну на компонет, скорее всего это то что я искал